# TypeScript: Is there a way to check infinite nested array type?

Tags: typescript

Here is an [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Item%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20ItemsArray%20extends%20Array%3CItemAny%3E%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20ItemAny%20%3D%20%5BItem%20%7C%20ItemsArray%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20SingleOrArray%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%7C%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20area%3A%20ItemAny%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'test1'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'test2'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'test3'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'test4'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'test5'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'test6'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'test7'%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%0D%0A%5D%3B)

The basic idea is - I have a type which can be plain object, or array of objects.

```
type SingleOrArray<T> = T | T[];
```

And I have structure like this:

```
const area: ItemArea = [
  { name: 'test1' },
  { name: 'test2' },
  [
    { name: 'test3' },
    { name: 'test4' },
    [
      { name: 'test5' },
      { name: 'test6' },
      [
        { name: 'test7' },
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

How I can restrict each element of this nested array with:

```
type Item = { name: string };
```

thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `type` because `type` cannot repeat itself. But you can use `interface`

This is the interface match your `area` constant

```
interface ItemArea {
    [n: number]: {
        name: string
    } | ItemArea;
};
```